# Event Handler inside for views inside a fragment

Tags: android

I am going through my first viewpager example. It consists of two fragement, one with a textview and one with an imageview. Here is the code for fragment with imageview:

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
private final int imageResourceId ;

public ImageFragment (int imageResourceId)
{
 this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
}
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 Log.e("Test","Hello");
}
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   

savedInstanceState)
{
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, container,false);
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 ImageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

 return view;
}

}
```

How can I implement a click handler for this imageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `onClickListener`?

You can set:

```
imageView.setClickable(true);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{...});
```

as usual, It is doesn't master whether it is in a fragment or whatever.

Comment: Ok, but where in the fragment class? In the onCreateView() function?

Comment: Thank you dymnneh to save my bad spelling.

Comment: afaik the listener is attached to the view, so inside onCreateView should be fine.

Comment: Yes, you can add the OnClickListener in onCreateView().